# All the icons in the Navigation Bar is coming black

Tags: java, android-studio, logcat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vh6O.png)
The image is coming black and idk why, I used the images properly and I am using java as a backend.

Answer (score 1):

I think icons are successfully imported. give white color(or any other color) to icons. it will show you icons.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your icons and re-importing them. If it still doesn't work that means maybe the file type you are using is not supported try some different images with different format and if it is still not visible then let me know.

Also I created a similar project of news, you can seek for any help direct via similar implementations from here: [NerdyNews](https://github.com/Sagar0-0/NerdyNews)